# Unable to install django

Tags: python, django, pip

When I install `Django-1.8.18` by using `pip`, it shows:

```
>>> pip install django
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install django
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And if I use winpython control panel, it shows:

```
invalid mode('wb') or filename: 'c:\\users\\lenovo\\appdate\\local\\temp\\wppm_8ohady\\Django_1.8.18\\tests\\staticfiles_tests\\apps\\test\\static\\test\\xe2\\x8a\\x37.txt'
```

Comment: Try `C:\user\> easy_install django==1.8` on your command prompt which is preferably running with adminstrator access, if you are using windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to run it from Python shell.
Run `pip install django` from the Windows command prompt instead of the Python shell.